# How do i unit test using mocha/chai/sinon if a variable has a react component as value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, components, mocha.js

I have a variable which gets dynamically assigned a React component based on a condition is true or false.

```
if(isValid) {icon = <ErrorIcon className: "error"/>}
else {icon = <SuccessIcon className: "success"/>
```

how do i test for expected value of icon is one component or other in unit test?

Comment: As an aside: you could write the above a bit better as:

```icon = isValid ? <ErrorIcon className="error" /> : <SuccessIcon className="success" />```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how reliable this API but each react component instance has a `type` property, so you can check it against the component definition:

```
const isErrorIcon = icon.type === ErrorIcon
```

So in your case:

```
expect(icon.type).to.equal(ErrorIcon)
```

Comment: Well you can `assert(isErrorIcon === true)` or something similar (depending on your test environment )

Comment: i'm using mocha, sinon. trying something like expect(icon).to.equal(<ErrorIcon />)

Comment: so try with `icon.type`, something along  `expect(icon.type).to.equal(ErrorIcon)` note i omitted the tag triangles  (`</>`)

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (icon.type === SuccessIcon) {

} else if (icon.type === ErrorIcon) {

}
```

Should do the trick.